# Search only inside a specific namespace in Object Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Its possible to search the Object Browser of Visual Studio 2022 with typing something in the search bar.
However, this searches all namespaces, what is usually a way too much.

Can you tell me if there is any way how one can search only one namespace?
For example in this screenshot I would like to search only inside PnP.Framework:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify to search in PnP.Framework by adding PnP.Framework to the custom component set. The following is the method of adding log4net.Core to the custom component set:

1. Select Edit Custom Component Set in the Browser of the Object Browser

[image]

2. Go to the bin/Debug folder of the solution under Browse to select the graphics card and find the corresponding dll

[image]

3. Click the corresponding dll=>click Add=>click OK

[image]

4. At this time, the search in Custom Component Set can only be searched in log4net.Core

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was it - I tried myself with the custom component set, but was not aware that I could add a DLL via "Browse".